# Efficient calculation for L-Kurtosis?

Tags: software, statistics

I am doing some statistical signal analysis and was wondering if there are any C/Java packages that do L-moment calculations, specifically L-Kurtosis as I am wanting to do things such as differentiating delta trains and sine waves with similar standard deviations, as one example.

If there are other more appropriate shape statistics to use, I would appreciate any information there as well.

Comment: cross-posted at [Cross-Validated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/153768/205311)

Answer (score 1):

You might be interested in the R package [Lmoments](https://rdrr.io/cran/Lmoments/man/Lmoments.html). [Here is the documentation for it](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/Lmoments/Lmoments.pdf), as well. According to it, the package is capable of computing at least L-scale, Lskewness, L-kurtosis.

While this is technically not a C/Java package, there are a lot of ways to call an R-function from C. For example, [this](http://pabercrombie.com/wordpress/2014/05/how-to-call-an-r-function-from-c/). Moreover, according to the Lmoments package documentation:

> `Lmoments_calc` and `Lmomcov_calc` are internal C++ functions called by Lmoments and Lmomcov. The direct use of these functions is not recommended.

So, you might give it a try and go against the advice.